# YouTube API Quota Limits & Applications that Scale

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm currently working on an app that requires video uploading via youtube. I plan to share the video in app via the the youtube API. According to the documentation to share a video on youtube requires "approximately 16000 units.", with each app having a complementary quota of 5 million allowing aprox. 312 video posts a day.

This app will have thousands of users so the "complementary" quota limit most definitely won't be enough, in the app dashboard when pressing "Request more..." the following message is displayed: "We Are Not Approving Quota Requests."

Obviously there are many apps out there with millions of users such as "Social cam" or "Talking Tom" that would be exceeding the complementary quota.

So my question is how can app increase its quota? If it is paid for what is the pricing structure?

Comment: _To share a video on youtube requires "approximately 16000 units."_ What does this refer to? Which YouTube Data API v3 method are you calling and where did you read that it consumes 16,000 quota units?

Comment: Quota documentation can be found on the [getting started site](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota)
.
I downloaded an example from [obj-c sample site](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FExamples%2FYouTubeSample), uploaded a video and that used 16000 quota.

Comment: Okay, so by "share a video" you meant uploading. That's what I wasn't sure about.

Comment: Ok glad we cleared that up so do you know personally how to increase the quota or where I can find information to do so?

Comment: What actually a unit is ? what do they mean by 3000 units/second/user

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Can you pay to increase your quota?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Now a days the quota cost for uploading videos is about 1600 per video upload. And the quota limit is also decrease by 100000 per day. For uploading 312 videos per day can cost 312*1600=499200. Which is less than 100000 quota limit. But if you want more videos to be uploaded you can increase data limit by little knowledge of php.

```
  $rand_keys = array_rand($num);
  $comm=$num[$rand_keys];
```

Where $num is an array that contains keys, Whatever number you want. Each new request go to the next api key. By making 10 keys you can get 10 times than limit also. Other wise you have to apply for quotas.

Comment: @user6239042 If we can use more than one key then what is purpose of quota limit? Is it not agiaint Youtube temrs and condition ?